# Reinitializing code in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I started writing a Meteor app today, for an eCommerce site. This is some code in my `basic.js` file.

```
Router.route("/shop", function () {

  this.layout("shop");
  this.render("catalog");

});
```

When `/shop` is rendered, some code inside of `shop.js` is executed:

```
Template.shop.rendered = function () {
  if ($("figure").hasClass("selected")) {
    var
      productSelected = $("figure.selected"),
      productPrice = productSelected.data("price"),
      productTitle = productSelected.data("product"),
      productLocation = productSelected.find("a").attr("href");

    $(".product-title").html(productTitle);
    $(".product-cost").html(productPrice);
    $(".content__info__title--overview").find("a").attr("href", productLocation);
  }

  // Slideshow
  var galleryItems = $(".content").children("section");

  galleryItems.each(function () {
    var container = $(this);

    // Update slider when user clicks on the preview images
    container.on("click", ".move-down, .move-up", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      if ($(this).hasClass("move-down")) {
        nextSlide(container);
      } else {
        prevSlide(container);
      }

      if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
        var
          productPrice = $(this).data("price"),
          productTitle = $(this).data("product");

        $(".product-title").html(productTitle);
        $(".product-cost").html(productPrice);
      }
    });
  });

  // Next Slide
  function nextSlide(container, n) {
    var visibleSlide = container.find("figure.selected");

    if (typeof n === "undefined") {
      n = visibleSlide.index() + 1;
    }

    $("figure.selected").removeClass("selected");

    $(".content__products figure").eq(n).addClass("selected").removeClass("move-down").prevAll().removeClass("move-down move-up").addClass("hide-up").end().prev().removeClass("hide-up").addClass("move-up").end().next().addClass("move-down");
  }

  // Previous Slide
  function prevSlide(container, n) {
    var visibleSlide = container.find("figure.selected");

    if (typeof n === "undefined") {
      n = visibleSlide.index() - 1;
    }

    $("figure.selected").removeClass("selected");

    $(".content__products figure").eq(n).addClass("selected").removeClass("move-up hide-up").nextAll().removeClass("hide-up move-down move-up").end().next().addClass("move-down").end().prev().removeClass("hide-up").addClass("move-up");
  }

});
```

Now, this works perfectly fine when the app loads, but when I visit a different route and come back, the none of the code in `shop.js` work. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but I'd love some pointers.

Comment: what happened if you change `Template.shop.rendered` to `Template.catalog.rendered` ? also what you get running this on the Meteor `shell  meteor --version`

Comment: Changing `shop` to `catalog` worked! YES. thank @Ethaan! I'm running Meteor 1.0.3.2 and Meteorite version 0.9.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the template rendered from this

`Template.shop.rendered` 
 to

`Template.catalog.rendered`.

Since you want to render the `catalog route` not the `layout template`.

btw i was asking about the meteor version because on new 1.0.4 meteor version `Template.shop.rendered = function () {}` got deprecated instead now we use `Template.tabletsList.onRendered(function() {});`, try it run meteor update.

Comment: I ran the update and my code still works. Still, I'll update to the new syntax.

Answer (score 0):

[Ethaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3961546/ethaan) answered my question in the comments. I just had to change `Template.shop.rendered` to `Template.catalog.rendered`. Good grief!

Comment: opps i just posted an answer haha

Comment: This happens to me more than I like to admit. Commit this to your memory! it'll happen again.